# What's the most elegant way to re-write a bunch of these python functions?

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I have a bunch of text-processing functions that looks like this:

```
def sample_func(txt=None, file_input=None, file_output=None):
    if txt is None:
        raw_txt = get_text_from_file(file_input)
    else:
        raw_txt = txt

    cleaned_txt = re.sub(r'\n\n', '\n', raw_txt)

    if file_output is not None:
        write_text_to_file(cleaned_txt, file_output)
    return cleaned_txt
```

When you have 10+ of these it gets quite tedious.

This function is used to clean a long list of files, so the arguments would be fed at run-time and point to either strings (for parameter `txt`) or file names (for parameters `file_input`, `file_output`).  I have thought about perhaps using decorators but not sure how I would do it.

One method I have thought of is to feed in a parameter function to perform the actual cleaning, i.e.:

```
def clean_text_with_cleaner(cleaner_func, txt=None, file_input=None, file_output=None):
    if txt is None:
        raw_txt = get_text_from_file(file_input)
    else:
        raw_txt = txt

    cleaned_txt = cleaner_func(raw_txt)

    if file_output is not None:
        write_text_to_file(cleaned_txt, file_output)
    return cleaned_txt
```

Are there any other ways that are more elegant than this?

Answer (score 1):

```
def sample_func(txt=None, file_input=None, file_output=None):
    raw_txt = txt or get_text_from_file(file_input) 
    cleaned_txt = re.sub(r'\n\n', '\n', raw_txt)    
    write_text_to_file(cleaned_txt, file_output) # handle file_output is None in this other function
    return cleaned_txt
```

might be considered cleaner by some ... others might dislike this method ...